# Flutter: Load FontAwesome icon based on api

Tags: flutter, dart, font-awesome

Getting api response like this

```
"sample_response": 
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "icon": "fa-ambulance",
                }
```

for static icon i used

```
  icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.gamepad),
```

How to load icon based on the json response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by [Font Awesome Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter).

There is another package to help you with that: [Icons Helper](https://pub.dev/packages/icons_helper)

However, if you try right now, you will see that [Icons Helper](https://pub.dev/packages/icons_helper) refers to an `adobe` icon that does not exist anymore. It has been removed from the package in the [master on Git](https://github.com/VoltaireApp/icons_helper) but not yet on PubDev.

You could also just integrate [icons_helper.dart](https://github.com/VoltaireApp/icons_helper/blob/master/lib/icons_helper.dart) in your project and maintain the map you need in your app.

Comment: if you need a more up to date map (based on font awesome 6): https://gist.github.com/philippkeller/2e017e43ff4d9472cba655031698abaa